# Need to test Windows 10 mobile build with .appx extension

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I need to test a windows 10 mobile application with extension .appx. I dont have any physical device, Please tell me the prerequisites and steps for testing the windows 10 mobile app in windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Windows 10 Mobile Extension SDK installed, along with Visual Studio 2015? If so you can use the emulator to test your application (although it won't be exactly the same as using a real device).